# iOS Core Data Relationship fetch

Tags: ios, core-data

I have this Core Data Model Hierarchy, with the respective relationships to each other:

Parks -> Zones -> Animals

I want to display the Name of the Park a selected animal belongs to in a label.

I would guess this would be done as below, but I'm not able to get the name attribute of Park because Park is coming as NSManagedObject and not as a Park object.

```
self.parkLabel.text = animal.zone.park.name;
```

Any Clues?

Comment: Show full core data scheme screenshot and core for generated classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this

```
Park *park = (Park *)animal.zone.park;
```

then

```
self.parkLabel.text = park.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast to a `Park` object, then.

```
self.parkLabel.text = ((Park *)animal.zone.park).name;
```